# How to export the result of pagerank as csv file to the disk in GraphLab Create?

Tags: csv, pagerank, graphlab

Hello I was reaing this tutorial written by Shawn about getting started on GraphLab Create right here

http://graphlab.com/learn/notebooks/getting_started_with_graphlab_create.html#

which is really helpful.

And I got a question that how to export the result of pagerank as csv file to the disk?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example is given in the [API docs](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.pagerank.create.html#graphlab.pagerank.create).

```
>>> g = graphlab.load_graph('http://snap.stanford.edu/data/email-Enron.txt.gz', format='snap')
>>> pr = graphlab.pagerank.create(g)
>>> pr_out = pr['pagerank']
```

That final SFrame, `pr_out`, can be saved as a csv file as follows:

```
pr_out.save('pagerank_values.csv', format='csv')
```